# A question about the standard input stream std::cin and how it parses out double and ints

Tags: c++, stl, iostream, cin

i am reading programming: principles and practice using c++. Currently im doing exercices for chapter 3, however one kind of stumped me. Now i was able to get the code working and all, but i was perplexed more about the programs reaction to my input.

Here's the question:
Write a program that prompts the user to enter two integer values. Store these values in int variables named val1 and val2. Write your program to determine the smaller, larger, sum, difference, product, and ratio of these values and report them to the user.

Here is my code:

```
   cout << "Hello, please enter two integers: ";

   int val1;
   int val2;
   int garbage;

   cin >> val1 >> val2 >> garbage;

   cout << "Val1: " << val1
     << "\nVal2: " << val2
     << "\nGarbage: " << garbage << '\n';


   if (val1 < val2)
    cout << "\nval1 is smaller than val2.";

   if (val1 > val2)
    cout << "\nval1 is bigger than val2.";

   int sum = val1 + val2;
   int difference = val1 - val2;
   int product = val1 * val2;
   double ratio = 1.0 * val1 / val2;

   cout << "\nRatio: " << ratio
     << "\nSum: " << sum
     << "\nDifference: " << difference
     << "\nProduct: " << product << '\n';
```

Can somehow explain to me more in depth what is supposed to happen in this situation regarding what the operator >> and cin are doing behind the scenes, and why ratio becomes "inf" after i input the string "90.8 9" in my program?

Thank you.

Now what i have done instead of inputting straight ints is to input doubles to see what would happen. Now obviously i am aware that cin parses out values according to which type the second operand of the >> operator is. But what i have done is input the following string into the program: "90.8 and 9"

Somehow the ratio variable is output on the screen as "inf"
and val2 is 0.

Val2 could be zero because of how >> operates, which is that if it detects a string when it is supposed to detect an int for an integer variable, >> adjusts the value of the second operand to 0. But i am not sure...

The "garbage" variable is just for me, i thought that cin did the following: See the value 90, input the value 90 in val1, see a string with the characters .8 and input 0 in val2, input 9 into garbage.
But for some reason 9 is not being inputted in "garbage". Garbage is now a literal garbage value with a random integer inside of it.

Here's the output of my program:

```
Hello, please enter two integers: 90.8 9
Val1: 90
Val2: 0
Garbage: -858993460

val1 is bigger than val2.
Ratio: inf
Sum: 90
Difference: 90
Product: 0
```

Comment: when you print the value of `val1` and `val2` what do you get? Please include the complete output in the question

Comment: you are mixing two things that can be considered seperately. One is how `std::cin` parses the input and the other is what happens in this line `double ratio = 1.0 * val1 / val2;` for certain values of `val1` and `val2`

Comment: I have added some extra context (my output)

Comment: Would you agree that your program does nothing to handle invalid `int` input, such as `.`?  Are you asking what happens when input is invalid?

Comment: Have you typed litterally `90.8 and 9`? Or have you typed `90.8`, then typed `9` (after a space, carriage return or whatever)? The sentence and quotes in your question (*what i have done is input the following string into the program: "90.8 and 9"*) suggest the former but you had better be as explicit as possible.

Comment: I mean yes i would have to agree, but what im wondering is how is cin parsing my input

Comment: I typed "90.8 9" Just a space in between.

Comment: I did not enter any quotes. Just the plain string inside the quotes "90.8 9"

Comment: The stream doesn't parse anything. It's the **extractors** (`>>`) that do the parsing. The stream is just a source of bytes.

Comment: Yes i am aware that cin is just a stream, and that >> do the extracting part, sometimes i just explain it a bit shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
cin >> val1 >> val2 >> garbage;
```

When you enter `90.8 9`, what happens in the following:

1. `operator>>` tries to read an `int` value. It successfully parses `90` and stores that in `val1`.
2. The next `operator>>` tries to parse another `int` value, but it encounters the `.` character. Hence, extraction of the `int` value fails and `0` is assigned to `val2`. `operator>>` puts `std::cin` into a fail state and no further extraction will happen on `std::cin` until you clear that state.
3. `cin` does not attempt to extract any more because it is in a fail state. Hence the next `operator>>` will not assign `0` to `garbage`, hence `garbage` has an indeterminate value. You cannot read it or print it to the screen. Your code does it nevertheless, which means your code has undefined behavior, its output could be anything.

This thing about assigning `0` was only introduced in C++11. And I still find it somewhat surprising that `operator>>` works like this when it fails in compound expressions. You can either check the state of `cin` after the extractions, and if any failed then assume that all of them failed.

```
if (cin >> val1 >> val2 ) {
   // ok
} else { 
   // either val1 and/or val2 were not successfully extracted
}
```

Or alternatively, use separate expressions for each extraction and check the failure state after each one:

```
if (cin >> val1) {
    // successfully read 
    // val1 is safe to use 
else {
    // handle failure
}
if (cin >> val2) {
   ...etc...
```

---

Then, in this line:

```
double ratio = 1.0 * val1 / val2;
```

When `val1 = 90` and `val2 = 0`, what happens is that `1.0 * val1` is evaluated first to yield a value of `val1` but as a `double`. The line is basically the same as:

```
double ration = static_cast<double>(val1) / val2;
```

Hence the division uses floating-point division, not integer-division where division by 0 is undefined. Hence the result is `inf`.

Comment: So that would be that if i do integer division with the last operand being 0, my program would probably crash, which is what happened. I did cin.clear() and you are indeed right. But the thing that suprises me more is the fact that cin is like this, why wouldn't it read the .8 is my input a double or a string?

Comment: @book_solver you told it to read an `int`.   `".8"` is not a representation of an  `int`

Comment: @book_solver I am not actually sure what confuses you. You can try `char x; std::cin << val1 << x << val2;` then enter `90.8` to see what happens like here https://godbolt.org/z/7zGaEW18P. Does that help to understand?

Comment: Fair enough, but what if i enter 90 0.8 9, now everything works fine with this being my output: Hello, please enter two integers: 90 0.8 9
Val1: 90
Val2: 0
Garbage: 0

val1 is bigger than val2.
Ratio: inf
Sum: 90
Difference: 90
Product: 0. The double here gets cropped (that i do know)

Comment: That would mean that cin doesnt parse numbers that don't have a number before a decimal?

Comment: Yes i know i am sorry, i have trouble getting it into words

Comment: @book_solver With `90 0.8 9` extraction fails exactly like I explained in the answer just one step later. `90` can be extracted. then `0` can be extracted. Then `.8` is encountered which cannot be parsed as `int`, hence `garbage` gets `0` assigned.

Comment: @book_solver use input without `0` to not get confused by the `0` that is assgned by `cin` and initialize your variables to a value you can also distinguish from `0` and from the input

Comment: Actually thanks does kind of does explain it for me well, maybe im reaching a bit too far haha. Thank you.